# Send data from CasperJS script to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, casperjs

I’m trying to get data from [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org) like this:

Contents of `file.php`:

```
$casperjs = "casperjs";
$script = 'add_site.js';
$arg0 = $_POST['new_site'];  
$command = "$casperjs $script $arg0";
$result = shell_exec($command);
echo $result;
```

Contents of `casperjs.js`:

```
casper.then(function() {
  // some code
  utils.dump(JSON.stringify(site));
});
casper.run(function() {
  this.exit();
});
```

I have nothing on output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% on CasperJS, but looking at your PHP code try using [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) in your script like this:

```
$casperjs = "casperjs";
$script = 'add_site.js';
$arg0 = $_POST['new_site'];  
$command = "$casperjs $script $arg0";
$result = shell_exec($command);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Also try setting explicit JSON headers for your output like this:

```
$casperjs = "casperjs";
$script = 'add_site.js';
$arg0 = $_POST['new_site'];  
$command = "$casperjs $script $arg0";
$result = shell_exec($command);
$json_data = json_encode($result);
header('X-JSON: (' . $json_data . ')');
header('Content-type: application/x-json');
echo $json_data;
```

Comment: Thanks for decision!
It starts to show output.
If I add headers it becomes to download file if I launch it directly.
But now I have another problem. I have "null" output.
I have success output when launch caseprjs script in SSH.
What problem it can be or how can I get where is mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with casperjs.

PHP must be so:

```
$casperjs = "/home/k/kreker92/casperjs/bin/casperjs";
$script = 'add_site.js';
$arg0 = $_POST['new_site'];
putenv("PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/home/k/kreker92/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs");
$command = "$casperjs $script $arg0";
$result = shell_exec($command);
$json_data = json_encode($result);
```